# How to solve "SpringBoard quit unexpected" issues on iOS with Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin

How to resolve "SpringBoard quit unexpected" issues?

I don't use Test Cloud, would anyone be able to explain in detail what is happening?

> Process: SpringBoard [7365] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
>   Identifier: SpringBoard Version: 1.0 (50) Code Type: X86 (Native)
>   Parent Process: launchd_sim [7247] Responsible: launchd_sim [7247]
>   User ID: 501
>
> Date/Time: 2015-07-12 18:27:14.767 +0700 OS Version: Mac OS X 10.10.4
>   (14E46) Report Version: 11 Anonymous UUID:
>   4F86C8E2-284F-6FD5-30D3-E2519C6D5409
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 36000 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread: 8 Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.frontboard.applicationLibrary.taskQueue
>
> Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application is required.'
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException abort() called
>   CoreSimulator 110.4 - Device: iPhone 4s - Runtime: iOS 8.1 (12B411) -
>   DeviceType: iPhone 4s
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0 CoreFoundation 0x0821c946
>   exceptionPreprocess + 182 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x07cffa97
>   objc_exception_throw + 44 2 CoreFoundation 0x0821c7da +[NSException
>   raise:format:arguments:] + 138 3 Foundation 0x04059810
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118 4
>   FrontBoard 0x01d09b66 __47-[FBApplicationLibrary
>   applicationsDidInstall:]block_invoke_2 + 335 5 FrontBoard 0x01d0998f
>   __47-[FBApplicationLibrary applicationsDidInstall:]_block_invoke + 1784 6 libdispatch.dylib 0x087f303f _dispatch_client_callout + 14 7
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x087dadb8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 79 8
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x087da8ea dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 105 9
>   libdispatch.dylib 0x087dae40 dispatch_barrier_sync + 54 10 FrontBoard
>   0x01d091ca -[FBApplicationLibrary applicationsDidInstall:] + 292 11
>   MobileCoreServices 0x060e5ce9 -[LSApplicationWorkspaceRemoteObserver
>   applicationsDidInstall:] + 233 12 CoreFoundation 0x080ff76d __invoking
>   + 29 13 CoreFoundation 0x080ff618 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 360 14 Foundation 0x041913fd
>   NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_EXPORTED_OBJECT + 30 15 Foundation
>   0x0401f568 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeMessageWithData:] + 1881
>   16 Foundation 0x0401bbb5 message_handler + 721 17 Foundation
>   0x0401b8cd __51-[NSXPCConnection
>   initWithMachServiceName:options:]_block_invoke + 20 18 libxpc.dylib
>   0x08ac1973 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 65 19 libxpc.dylib
>   0x08ac1779 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2278 20 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x087f3121 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 37 21 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x087e35a9 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 318 22 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x087dbc1b _dispatch_queue_drain + 527 23 libdispatch.dylib 0x087e3ab7
>   _dispatch_mach_invoke + 225 24 libdispatch.dylib 0x087dbc1b _dispatch_queue_drain + 527 25 libdispatch.dylib 0x087db8ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 197 26 libdispatch.dylib 0x087dd9e7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 367 27 libdispatch.dylib 0x087de985 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108 28 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b491da _pthread_wqthread + 724 29 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b46e2e start_wqthread + 30
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b169ce mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b15a70 mach_msg + 68 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08136026 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08135408 __CFRunLoopRun + 1400 4
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08134bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443 5
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x081349fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6
>   com.apple.GraphicsServices 0x043ef24f GSEventRunModal + 192 7
>   com.apple.GraphicsServices 0x043ef08c GSEventRun + 104 8
>   com.apple.UIKit 0x0096d8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526 9
>   com.apple.springboard 0x0007e4b0 0x76000 + 33968 10 libdyld.dylib
>   0x08819ac9 start + 1
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b1d8ce kevent64 + 10 1 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x087e23be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 245 2 libdispatch.dylib 0x087e2116
>   _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60
>
> Thread 2: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b169ce mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b15a70 mach_msg + 68 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08136026 CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08135408 __CFRunLoopRun + 1400 4
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08134bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443 5
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x081349fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6
>   com.apple.Foundation 0x03fecd98 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop)
>   runMode:beforeDate:] + 309 7 com.apple.Foundation 0x0408c67b
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82 8 com.apple.UIKit 0x00ea982b -[UIStatusBarServerThread main] + 796 9 com.apple.Foundation 0x03feae60 __NSThread__main + 1326 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x08b48e13 _pthread_body + 138 11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b48d89
>   _pthread_start + 162 12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b46e52 thread_start + 34
>
> Thread 3: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b169ce mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x08b15a70 mach_msg + 68 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08136026 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08135408 __CFRunLoopRun + 1400 4
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x08134bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443 5
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x081349fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6
>   com.apple.springboard 0x000f5592 0x76000 + 521618 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b48e13 _pthread_body + 138 8
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b48d89 _pthread_start + 162 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x08b46e52 thread_start + 34xamarin.

I'm finding it impossible to solve.

Comment: your crash is due to "Application is required." which is abit vague. Are you able to edit your question with any of your code? e.g. how the app starts?

Comment: I'm not writing code yet. Just design.